# Best place to store driver JAR's on .jsp application hosted on Tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, driver

I've been quizzing my mentor, but he isn't sure on the answer.
I'm building a JSP based application to be hosted on a tomcat server. It connects to several different types of SQL database. Where is the best place to store the drivers? We can't decide between adding to a lib folder in the application, or whether to add them to the lib folder of tomcat.
I'm using Eclipse to build the application and setting the buildpath for the app, rather than setting the classpath of the machine.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Db drivers normally go in the Container lib folder as different apps might use the same driver. Just to give you an idea an Application Server like JBoss provides drivers and libraries to connect to databases and other resources.
Another advantage it makes your WAR file a bit smaller.

Comment: Thank you, this does make sense, however if deploying to a different server than I have developed the app on, does this mean I'll have to set all the build paths either relative, or to the location of the destination server before I export the app?
     I ask because if it were held internally to the app, there would be no configuration required should the app be deployed on different servers?

Comment: Well, yes, it really depends on your need. 

An application which needs to be packaged, shipped and deployed into an environment you dont control should better include these libraries, thats also a way forward (however there are other challenges here as you dont know if the same library is maybe provided already).

You application might include some pre-requisites (how to install it) or maybe you want to look at Docker where you can package all you need in an image